# Is there a way to sort shape keys by name?

Tags: shape-keys

Anybody know of a way to sort the shape keys by name, it gets quite annoying puzzle if there is an extended list of them. Be nice if it would be implemented in the specials menu like with the vertex groups. Or at least a function call like `py.ops.object.shape_keys_sort(sort_type='NAME')`.

Answer (score 2):

On the "Object Data" tab in the "Shape Keys" panel; click the tiny + symbol at the lower left of the shape key list.

[image: Shape key list]

This will enable the filtering and sorting options

[image: Shape key list]

Clicking the AZ button sorts the list alphabetically.

(The tooltip lists the relevant python command as MESH_UL_shape_keys.use_filter_sort_alpha)

These filtering options/sorting options are hidden away in all (most?) of these lists.